# jQuery's change of isNumeric (in latest versions)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Until recent version , jQuery used to check if numeric via :

`return !isNaN( parseFloat(obj) ) && isFinite( obj );`

The *first* part is for :

- `parseFloat("d") //Nan`
- `!isNaN( parseFloat(Infinity)) //true but not a number`

The *second* part is for :

- `isFinite('2') //true`

But in recent version they changed it and changed it to :

```
return !jQuery.isArray(obj) && (obj - parseFloat(obj) + 1) >= 0;
```

**Question:**

What was *not good enough* in the previous version that they changed it to the new one ? And why do they check if array?

Comment: For speed and drop some possible errors I think. If obj is array, than everything after `&&` will be omitted.

Comment: See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/b6e99eb43c35a3cd048c5c56d31c7e871f299a77 - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/15100

Comment: also http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14313

Comment: I think using the https://github.com/jquery/jquery history will give you a better picture on why and how those changes come in

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The same value of `obj` answers both your questions : `[3]`

`!isNaN( parseFloat(obj) ) && isFinite( obj )` is `true` for `[3]`.

`(obj - parseFloat(obj) + 1) >= 0` is `true` for `[3]`.

The reason behind those problems is that a conversion to string or number occurs in [`parseFloat`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.3) and in [`isFinite`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.5) and that the conversion to string of an array is the result of joining with commas the conversion of its elements to strings.

So this change is a bug fix.

Note that you can still make it "fail" with values like `{toString:function(){ return 3}}` but it's unclear what jQuery should really return in such a case (this object really *wants* to appear as a number, after all).

Comment: Shouldn't you fill a new bug report?

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm not sure. Suppose you make such an object, you probably have good reasons, so probably it should be considered as a number. And when you do it, it's not by chance.

Comment: From DOC: `The $.isNumeric() method checks whether its argument represents a numeric value.` Seems fair indeed

Comment: @DenysSéguret Any Idea why all those math  operations in `(obj - parseFloat(obj) + 1) >= 0 ` ? I already know that 1 - '3'  = -2 but why this `x- parseFloat(x)+1 >= 0` check ? . I other words , what is it solving ?

Answer (score 7):

The previous version, for example, didn't correctly work for arrays that had a single numeric element:

```
var obj = [1];
(!isNaN( parseFloat(obj) ) && isFinite(obj)); //true
var obj = [1, 2];
(!isNaN( parseFloat(obj) ) && isFinite(obj)); //false
```

Comment: Could you explain your question? This bug is exactly what the update fixes.