# understand jQuery isNumeric source code

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is code snippet of `isNumeric` method from [jQuery code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bb026fc12c3c2ad37f47f0919e484bddcdc3d291/src/core.js):

```
isNumeric: function( obj ) {
    // parseFloat NaNs numeric-cast false positives (null|true|false|"")
    // ...but misinterprets leading-number strings, particularly hex literals ("0x...")
    // subtraction forces infinities to NaN
    // adding 1 corrects loss of precision from parseFloat (#15100)
    return !jQuery.isArray( obj ) && (obj - parseFloat( obj ) + 1) >= 0;
},
```

I don't understand the comment: `// parseFloat NaNs numeric-cast false positives (null|true|false|"")`

What does it mean? After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980010/jquerys-change-of-isnumeric-in-latest-versions), I still don't understand the meaning of this comment.

Comment: You should test it. The way I read it it will return *true* if it you feed it [`nan`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). Which would be confusing.

Comment: No,  parseFloat( NaN ) definitely returns NaN, and `isNumeric` returns _false_. Even with the older version `return !isNaN( parseFloat(obj) ) && isFinite( obj );` isNumeric(NaN) still returns _false_